# On click of radio button, add class to parent

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, which when you click a radio button it adds the class `checked_radio`, when you click on another radio button it removes the class then adds the class to another radio button. That works great.

The second part is that I want to do a similar thing but add the class `highlighted` to the parent li, it adds it fine but doesn't remove the class when clicking on another radio button. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.gfield_radio input').click(function() {
   $('.gfield_radio input').removeClass("checked_radio");
   $(this).addClass("checked_radio");

   $('input.checked_radio').closest('li').removeClass("highlighted");
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('highlighted');   
});
```

Comment: y you not just do it like above and remove highlighted class from every .checked_radio class.

Comment: I couldn't find any issue in your code... Can you show us a not working demo?

Comment: can you post the html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With these lines, you ensure that any previous `.gfield input` no longer has `checked_radio` and then add it to the one just clicked:

```
$('.gfield_radio input').removeClass("checked_radio");
$(this).addClass("checked_radio");
```

but then, after doing that, you use this to try to remove the old highlight:

```
$('input.checked_radio').closest('li').removeClass("highlighted");
```

Of course, by then, you've already updated which radio button has the `checked_radio` class.

Just change the sequence:

```
$('.gfield_radio input').click(function() {
   // Out with the old...
   $('input.checked_radio').closest('li').removeClass("highlighted");
   $('.gfield_radio input').removeClass("checked_radio");

   // ...and in with the new
   $(this).addClass("checked_radio")
          .closest('li').addClass('highlighted');   
});
```

Comment: I was so slower to understand the fact even after seeing your answer while you posted the answer so faster. Nice one! I wish you could my bestie.

Answer (score 0):

The great way to do is like as @T.J.Crowder has given to you.

You can also use:

```
$('.gfield_radio input').click(function() {
   $('.gfield_radio input').removeClass("checked_radio");
   $(this).addClass("checked_radio");

   //or may be $('.gfield_radio li').removeClass('highlighted');
   $('.gfield_radio input').closest('li').removeClass("highlighted");
   $(this).closest('li').addClass('highlighted');   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
// Cache your selectors so you're not always calling the jQuery method
var $radios = $('.gfield_radio input'),
    $listItems = $('.gfield_radio li');

// Listen to the `change` event instead of `click`, to ensure that it
// only happens when the user has explicitly changed the radio's value
$radios.on('change', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
      // Ensure you grab the correct `li` by using `parents()`
      $parent = $this.parents('li');

  // Now you can remove/add classes as you need without having to call
  // `jQuery()` again and again.
  $radios.removeClass('checked_radio');
  $listItems.removeClass('highlighted');
  $this.addClass('checked_radio');
  $parent.addClass('highlighted');

});
```

Similar to other answers, but cleaned up a little bit. Hope this helps.